# TextBox binding is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, textbox, command

I have two `UserControls`:

1) `ContactDetailsView`.

2) `SearchBarView`.

In the`SearchBarView`, I have a `Search` button, which raises a command when clicked: `Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"`

In the `SearchBarView` code behind, I have the following code: `DataContext = new SearchBarViewModel();`

In the `ContactDetailsView` I have the following code:

`xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:Accounts_Manager.UserControls.SearchBar"` in the definition of the `UserControl` and this code underneath it:

`<UserControl.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:SearchBarViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>`

I also have a `TextBox` with the following definition:

`<TextBox x:Name="ContactNameTextBox" FontFamily="Times New Roman" Foreground="DarkRed" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="False" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ContactId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>`

I have a class called `SearchBarViewModel` with the following code:

```
    public string ContactId
    {
        get { return m_contactId; }
        set
        {
            m_contactId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ContactId");
        }
    }
    public ICommand SearchCommand
    {
        get { return m_searchCommand ?? (m_searchCommand = new RelayCommand(SearchContact)); }
        set { m_searchCommand = value; }
    }
    public void SearchContact(object parameter)
    {
        CurrentContact = DbHandler.Search("עידן");

        ContactId = CurrentContact.FirstName + " " + CurrentContact.LastName;
        BankId = CurrentContact.BankName;
        AccountNumber = CurrentContact.AccountNumber.ToString();
    }
```

The class is defined like this; `SearchBarViewModel : ViewModelBase` where `ViewModelBase` inherits from `INotifyPropertyChanged` and implements it.

`RelayCommand` inherits from `ICommand` and implements it.

And now, after all this, my problem is that when I click the `Search` button, expecting the `TextBox` to be updated, I see that everything is being called and updated, the property is being raised, but the `TextBox` is not updated with the value of `ContactId`.

Any ideas?

Comment: This question is *very* well put, good job including all the relevant info!

Comment: Thanks a lot!I also looked at your answer and understood exactly what the problem is. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, you are using two different objects!

`DataContext = new SearchBarViewModel()` in the `SearchBarView` sets the DataContext where the button lives to an instance of `SearchBarViewModel`. No problem.

But you then do

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:SearchBarViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

In the other view, which *also* creates an instance of that object. Thus, the command invocation changes a variable on *its* instance of the view model, which the other instance obviously doesn't see.

User controls (like a search bar) usually don't have their own data context, you use dependency properties to allow the master VM to be have its properties bound to it. That is the approach I would take in your case. The other way to solve it would be to pass in a common instance to one or both of the controls so they are looking at the same object.

Comment: Hi again, could you please give me an example of what you meant with the `DependencyProperty`? Should it be defined in my `SearchBarViewModel` class? Do I need more than one? Thanks!!

Comment: @Idanis There are lots of examples online, could you be a bit more specific as to what you are looking for? For what its worth, DPs go on views (user control's) *not* view models. You need one for each property you wish to have as a binding target.